# Blockchain Beginner: How do I validate my SHA-256 hash submission, by converting it to a blockchain.info address?

Tags: timestamp, blockchain, sha256, trusted-timestamp, blockchain.info-api

I really need help here ... I know this is simple ... but if someone could explain this like they are talking to a ten year old I'd appreciate it

- I converted a JPEG to SHA-256
- I submitted that SHA-256 hash to the
  blockchain using origin stamp
- Now, I want to manually convert my
  original hash either from (Hex) or (Base64) into the "Address" given
  to me by originstamp so I can view the transaction on blockchain.info
  how do I do this? I CANNOT figure it out.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "converted a JPEG to SHA-256"? You mean you calculated the has of your JPEG? And you submitted your hash using origin stamps API? What do they return to you when done?

Comment: You can't convert your hash into an address, you would need to get that from origin stamps. Do they provide the txid?